# Angular 2 setInterval issue

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

when set interval executing , binded html input lost focus every second. i did not able to type. but when i comment set interval code it work fine. can you help me friends ?

```
countdown(){

        if (this.seconds <= 0) return;   

        this.countdownInterval = setInterval(()=> {
          if (this.seconds <= 0) {
        clearInterval(this.countdownInterval);

        this.toFinishNotify();       

      }
      this.seconds--;

    }, 1000);
  }

    htmlElement function return input text box <p [innerHtml]="htmlElement(obj) " > </p>
```

for example

to stop timer `dash`  when user `dash` click submit . `dash` can be converted into text boxes

Comment: I assume that missing `)` after milliseconds is a typo during copy-pasting?

Comment: yes sebastian..now i corrected

Comment: Why do you generate HTML using [innerHtml] in the first place? Why don't you use an HTML template? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: do you want to display in html timer countdown ?

Comment: @JB Nizet , getting text content from backend , its have word  `dash`  &  `dash` should be converted to text box. we dont know count of `dash`.thats why im using innerHtml

Comment: @Chandru, yes im displaying time countdown in html

Comment: So you're effectively asking angular, every second, to replace the inner HTML of your <p> with a different one. So that's what it does, and obviously the input that had the focus is destroyed every second. I think you really need to rethink your design.

Comment: no JB Nizet , timer run separately. its like quiz question answer concept.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

html file

```
<input type="text" id="timer">
```

**component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    countdownInterval: any;
    seconds: number = 30;

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        var display = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#timer');
        this.countdown(display);
    }

    countdown(display) {

        if (this.seconds <= 0) return;

        this.countdownInterval = setInterval(() => {
            if (this.seconds <= 0) {
                clearInterval(this.countdownInterval);
                this.toFinishNotify();

            }
            display.value = this.seconds;
            this.seconds--;

        }, 1000);
    }

    toFinishNotify() {
        console.log('toFinishNotify');
    }
}
```

Comment: displaying time have no problem. i have issue in dynamically generated textboxes lost focus when interval execute.